# Set Different Re-delivery Policy for each message in Queue of ActiveMQ 5.14

Tags: activemq-classic

I am building an application in which i have an **requirement to set different re delivery policy for each message** as i want to redeliver the message only based on some message condition.Below i already tried but its for queue.

```
RedeliveryPolicy policy = connection.getRedeliveryPolicy();policy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(500);policy.setBackOffMultiplier(2);policy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(2);
```

Also i don't want to use different queue as i want a message to be executed in order.Please do Let me know if any one have any idea for it or is there any tweak which i can use to achieve same.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in ActiveMQ, the consumer applies the redelivery policy configured to each message that is delivered and subsequently redelivered by a TX rollback or Session.recover()